# Autoupdating when during Write-and-test stages

Tags: autocad, autolisp

This is a general question and not related to a specific bit of code.

How do you work when writing and testing a routine? My autocad doesn't "react" when I update the code with Notepad, so I have to close the file, open it again and then (load "filename") again.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I've searched a bit but couldn't find (or couldn't understand) the answers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **strongly** suggest using the development environment provided freely within AutoCAD to write, test & debug your code. This utility is known as the Visual LISP Integrated Development Environment (VLIDE).

I have written a [basic introduction tutorial](http://lee-mac.com/introtovlide.html) describing how to access & use this environment, but you can also find a wealth of information in the [standard documentation](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/AutoCAD-AutoLISP/files/GUID-50158F17-992B-4427-B64F-31EF77BECBD7-htm.html) provided by Autodesk.